# jqGrid search throwing exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Im using jquery and jqGrid plugin.
When i try to use form search in jqGrid a javascript exception is thrown in firebug.

uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@selected]

and reset is also not working
anyone please help me out....

Thanks,
Sandeep

edit:

```
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'/getdata.jsp',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['PSM ID','PSM Name','Responsibility','Date of Join(MM/dd/yyyy)','Date of Leaving(MM/dd/yyyy)','Designation','Organisation','Location','Phone Number','Email'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'PSM_EMP_ID',index:'PSM_EMP_ID',editable:false, width:75},
      {name:'PSM_EMP_Name',index:'PSM_EMP_Name',editable:true,width:100,editrules:{required:true,edithidden:false}}, 
      {name:'RESPONSIBILITY',index:'RESPONSIBILITY',editable:true,width:100}, 
      {name:'DATE_OF_JOIN',index:'DATE_OF_JOIN',width:90,editable:true,edittype:'text',editrules:{required:true},editoptions: {
          size: 10, maxlengh: 10,id:'datepicker1',dataInit: $(function(elem) {
          $("#datepicker1").datepicker({showOn: 'button',buttonImage:'/images/calendar.gif',
                buttonImageOnly: true});
          })
      }
      },
      {name:'DATE_OF_LEAVING', index:'DATE_OF_LEAVING', editable:true,width:110},
      {name:'DESIGNATION', index:'DESIGNATION',editable:true,editrules:{required:true},width:100},
      {name:'ORGANISATION', index:'ORGANISATION',editable:true,editrules:{required:true},width:180}, 
      {name:'LOCATION', index:'LOCATION', editable:true,editrules:{required:true},width:100}, 
      {name:'PSM_PHONE_NUMBER', index:'PSM_PHONE_NUMBER',editrules:{required:true},editable:true,width:100}, 
      {name:'PSM_EMAIL', index:'PSM_EMAIL', editable:true,editrules:{required:true},width:220}],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'user',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: false,
    multiselect:false,
    imgpath: '/themes/steel/images',
    caption: 'PSM',
    editurl: '/update.jsp', shrinkToFit: true
    /*width:1200 */}).navGrid('#pager',{add:true,addtext:'Add',edit:true,edittext:'Edit',del:true,deltext:'Del', search:true,searchtext:'Find'/*,refresh:true*/}, /*options*/
{height:300,width:500,reloadAfterSubmit:true}, /* edit options*/
{height:300,width:500,reloadAfterSubmit:true}, /* add options*/
{reloadAfterSubmit:true}, // del options
{} // search options
);
```

This is the code used...

Comment: You should include the code which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add following property to the 'DATE_OF_JOIN' column

```
searchoptions: {
    size: 10, maxlengh: 10,
    dataInit: function(elem) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(elem).datepicker({ showOn: 'button' });
        },100);
    }
}
```

and use jqGrid 4.0, where `showOn: 'button'` setting will work in searching dialog.

It will be additionally very good if you remove all unsed parameters of jqGrid (like very very old deprecated `imgpath` parameter) and parameters having default values (like `multiselect:false` and so on).

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sandeep.htm).

Comment: @Sandeep: What do you mean under **the demo is not working**? You don't include and data in your question, so my demo has no data. Your question was in the searching dialog. In my demo you can click the "Find" button in the navigator bar bottom on the grid, choose the 'Date of Join(MM/dd/yyyy)' field and enter the data. You will see that the datepicker work and no exception thrown.

Comment: i have copy pasted everything what u gave. when i click on find its throwing the same uncaught exception.

Comment: @Sandeep: Do you have the same problem if you use my demo? Why not? Where is the difference?

Comment: @Sandeep: Which version of jqGrid you use? Probably what you have is the bug which are fixed [here] (https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/89aa173d5fc884fb8aa02f64dfc7c5272c0125f2)?